# Error when building the project "unable to resolve class org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml"

Tags: validation, gradle, yaml, snakeyaml

We are trying to validate an yaml at the time of build in a gradle project. After adding the dependency "org.yaml.snakeyaml:2.2", and trying to use that on a task, I'm getting the error `unable to resolve class org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml` . Its throwing the even when I try to do `gradlew clean`.

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.yaml:snakeyaml:2.0'
}

task validateYaml {
    doLast {

        def yaml = new org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml()
        def data = yaml.load(PATH_OF_YAML)
    }
}
```

I tried with the older versions of snakeyaml. Its the same issue with any versions. Kindly let me know if there is anything I'm missing on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.yaml:snakeyaml:2.0'
}
```

you are making SnakeYAML a dependency of your application, not your build.

To add the dependency to the build, you need to use the [buildscript block](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:applying_plugins_buildscript), like so:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.yaml:snakeyaml:2.0'
    }
}
```